# How do I assign a new column to polars dataframe?

Tags: python-polars

In polars, I am trying to create a new column I already know the values of the columns and I just want to add a column with those values. Below is the code

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2], "b": [4, 5]})

english_titles = ["ok", "meh"]

df.with_columns(pl.lit(english_titles).alias("english_title"))
```

But the above doesn't work and I think it's because I am using `pl.lit` wrongly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A column is a `Series`

```
>>> type(df.get_column("a"))
polars.internals.series.series.Series
```

Meaning you can use `pl.Series` instead of `pl.lit`

```
>>> df.with_columns(english_title = pl.Series(english_titles))
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬───────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ english_title │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---           │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str           │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ ok            │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ meh           │
└─────┴─────┴───────────────┘
```

Comment: wish it was in the docs properly

Comment: @xiaodai It's somewhat shown in the [last example](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.lit.html) - although the `pl.lit()` can be omitted in your case. Perhaps you could suggest an improvement: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars-book/issues

Comment: @xiaodai The syntax you initially tried has just been added. It will be in tomorrow's release.